# How Do You Rapidly Benchmark Scripts

Tags: python, ruby, benchmarking

I've seen a lot of blogs where authors discuss throwing together quick benchmark tests, like this [Ruby 1.9.0 v Python 2.5.1](http://programmingzen.com/2007/11/28/holy-shmoly-ruby-19-smokes-python-away/) that Antonio Cangiano "throws together at 3am."

Is there a simple way to time a script to the millisecond like that that I'm unaware of? Is he probably using built-in functions of OS X or individual libraries? Does Python have a standard lib for this?

How would you do this if you were just going to take the path of least resistance and throw it together at 3am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after mere benchmarking, and you're not too worried about start-up time, and you want it to be programming language independent and you're on Unix, you'd probably use unix `time`:

```
time ruby -e "1.upto(10000000) {|i| i}"
real    0m2.926s
user    0m1.570s
sys 0m1.350s
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is probably the solution the author of that blog used, and this fits all of my rough criteria (as ill-defined as they were in this question.) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in Ruby, but in Python I do this -

```
import time
def my_function():
    a = time.clock()
    //code which you want to benchmark
    b = time.clock()
    print b-a
```

Obviously, this is a "throw together at 3am benchmark." No frills.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a [Benchmark](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/benchmark/frames) module as part of the standard distribution. It's simple to use. A [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+benchmark+user%3A128421) here on Stack Overflow will turn up a lot of samples of its use that I've done.

Answer (score 1):

for ruby benchmarking try this

```
require 'benchmark'
```

Benchmark.realtime do
     #your code,this 
   end

also try measure which give more detail total system time etc

```
Benchmark.measure do 

end
```